# meteor-geocoder reverse callback TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: meteor, google-geocoder

I get an error using reverse lookup with aldeed:geocoder@0.3.7:

```
var geo = new GeoCoder();
var addr = geo.reverse(45.767, 4.833);
```

Gives the error below:

```
W20151006-08:26:25.947(2)? (STDERR) C:\Users\steets\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\aldeed_geocode
r\0.3.7\npm\node_modules\node-geocoder\lib\geocoder.js:60                                        
W20151006-08:26:25.947(2)? (STDERR)                 return callback(err, data);                  
W20151006-08:26:25.947(2)? (STDERR)                        ^                                     
W20151006-08:26:25.947(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: number is not a function
```

This happens on both my development machine as in deployment.

Using node-inspector I have traced the problem to `Meteor.wrapAsync` at aldeed_geocoder.js:61:

```
GeoCoder.prototype.reverse = function geoCoderReverse(lat, lng, callback) {
  if (callback) {
    callback = Meteor.bindEnvironment(callback, function (error) {
      if (error) throw error;
    });
    rv(lat, lng, this.options, callback);
  } else {
    return Meteor.wrapAsync(rv)(lat, lng, this.options);
  }
};
```

(`rv` calls the `reverse` function of `node-geocoder`, mentioned in the error)

Then `wrapAsync` fails on the very last line:

```
return fut ? fut.wait() : result;
```

Running `meteor update` indicates I have the latest meteor and packages.

I tried to recreate this error in a vanilla app, following the package README (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-geocoder):

```
meteor create test
cd test
meteor add aldeed:geocoder
meteor
```

and then in a new terminal:

```
meteor shell
> var geo = new GeoCoder()
> geo.geocode('29 champs elysée paris')
[ { formattedAddress: '29 Av. des Champs-Élysées, 75008 Paris, France',
....
    zipcode: '75008' } ]
> geo.reverse(45.767, 4.833)

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:559:19)
```

This is a different error, but it still  doesn't work and maybe this is the underlying cause.

I recently upgraded to meteor 1.2. This code used to work fine under meteor 1.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am at a complete loss.

Comment: While I was typing this, the same appeared as an issue at https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-geocoder/issues/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug. Fixed by package maintainer :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround for now is to clone package to 'packages' folder in your project directory and change the wrong line, geocoder.js:34. It should look like this:

```
g.reverse({lat: lat, lon: lng}, callback);
```

I hope aldeed will fix issue in github soon. I'll try to make a PR now.